I am having Installation issues can someone help?
I am having issues getting my installation to populate on my URL any help is appreciated I am using joomla

Can you be more specific about the issues your are experiencing? That will dramatically improve your chance of getting useful answers.

What version of Joomla are you using?

4.xx when I think I am done installing everything I get no front end GUI. That’s my biggest issue right now and finding a good theme for Joomla??

I would gladly pay for someone to do the installation….

@NicW.B.C.T.P.S. sorry for this late response to your comment. If you are still looking for paid help the listing at https://civicrm.org/civicrm/experts is your friend.

Installed Joomla 4.4.4 and the newest version of CiviCRM, incl. CiviMobile.
Everything is working as intended now.
